# What is the correct way to close my question, whose relevance I am doubting

Tags: support, questions, self-answer

A couple of days ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19277988/2029629) for a problem I had.  I got no answers, but almost by chance I solved my problem.

I am not quite sure if the question and answer are really relevant given that the solution was so simple.  So I have a question on the question:

1. Should I answer it (moving current **Update 2** as an answer) and in a couple of days accept my own answer, so that question and answer are part of the archive?
2. Should I ask for an administrative closing of the question, so the question reminds in the archive but not as an answered question?
3. Should I ask for deletion of the question, so the question is removed for the archive?

Comment: Answer it yourself. Just because you think it's a simple answer now it clearly wasn't simple when you asked it - because you wouldn't have asked it. Therefore it's quite conceivable that someone else will have the same issue as you in future, so leaving an answer to it will help that future visitor out too.

Comment: @JonW you should give this as an answer this actually answer of the question

Comment: Update 2 is the core of something that could be an answer. Expand it, post it as an answer and you will have done the internet a great service. Remember to answer as if you are two different people, one asking, one answering. The quality rules are exactly the same whether you answer your question or someone elses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should answer your own question.  [That is encouraged on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

You shouldn't close it, flag it to be closed, or ask it to be deleted.  It's a legitimate question that may help someone in the future who has the same problem.

You shouldn't have the answer as an edit to the question itself.  Remove the answer from the question itself, and post your answer as an answer, separately.

Answer (score 5):

Post an answer to the question.

If you've found an answer it should be posted as an answer so that the answers contains answers and the questions contain questions.

That you found an answer doesn't mean a question should be closed.  If it should be closed for some reason other than that you found an answer (perhaps it didn't get answers because it's unclear, and you answered it because you knew information not in the post).  If the question should be closed, you're welcome to flag it and ask for it to be closed.  This is true even if you don't have an answer.

If you really think that nobody, ever, would be helped by seeing your solution then sure, delete it.  if it was a silly typo, for example, there may not be anyone helped by a posted answer.  But if you think that the answer might be able to help someone in a similar or related situation, then don't deprive them of that useful content by deleting the answer.  If you want the question to be deleted (given that it has no upvoted answers) you can delete it yourself using the "delete" link.  If it has upvoted answers then it can't be deleted since the community feels there is valuable information on the page worth keeping around.  Looking at your specific question, it's clearly not a problem that *only you* could ever possibly have, so it should not be deleted.

Comment: Too late.  It was deleted while I was writing the answer.